# Discord bot not reply

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

I setup node.js Bot is active but but it doesn't answer

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Project is running!");
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello world!")
})

const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "MESSAGE_CONTENT"]});

client.on("messageCreate", message => {
  if(message.content.toLowerCase() === "sa") {
    message.channel.send("as");
  }
})

client.login(process.env.token);
```

Program enters crash loop and gives this error:

```
/home/runner/Ilk-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/BitField.js:152
    throw new RangeError('BITFIELD_INVALID', bit);
    ^

RangeError [BITFIELD_INVALID]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: MESSAGE_CONTENT.
    at Function.resolve (/home/runner/Ilk-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/BitField.js:152:11)
    at /home/runner/Ilk-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/BitField.js:147:54
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.resolve (/home/runner/Ilk-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/BitField.js:147:40)
    at Client._validateOptions (/home/runner/Ilk-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:550:33)
    at new Client (/home/runner/Ilk-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:76:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/Ilk-Bot/index.js:13:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'BITFIELD_INVALID'
}
```

When i asked someone before he say me to add `MESSAGE_CONTENT`
I add the `MESSAGE_CONTENT` and got into crash loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DiscordJsv14 you would need to change 2 things

```
const client = new Client({
    intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent],
});
```

Please add this intent **and** activate in the discord developer portal the message intent.

[image]